# download azure blob to ftp upload, memory stays allocated?

Tags: c#, azure, memory-management, ftp, asp.net-core-2.0

i am having trouble releasing my memory when downloading from azure and upload it to a FTP account.

I have this piece of beautiful code:

```
private async Task<Result> DownloadFileAsync(ICloudBlobContainer container, string fileName, Func<MemoryStream, string, Task<Result>> onDownloaded)
{
    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

    if (await blob.ExistsAsync())
    {
        Result result;
        MemoryStream memoryStream;
        using (memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
            result = await onDownloaded(memoryStream, fileName);
            memoryStream.Close();
            memoryStream.Dispose();
        }
        memoryStream = null;

        return result;
    }

    _logger.LogWarning("Blob does not exists");
    return Result.Fail($"Blob '{fileName}' does not exist");
}
```

when eveything is downloaded to the stream, i pass the stream to `await onDownloaded(memoryStream, fileName);`

And that code is:

```
await client.LoginAsync();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_config.WorkingDirectory) &&
    !string.Equals(client.WorkingDirectory, "/" + _config.WorkingDirectory, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    await client.ChangeWorkingDirectoryAsync(_config.WorkingDirectory);
}

// File maybe already in 'use' (by other endpoint)
Stream writeStream;
using (writeStream = await client.OpenFileWriteStreamAsync(fileName))
{
    stream.Position = 0;
    await stream.CopyToAsync(writeStream);
    writeStream.Close();
    writeStream.Dispose();
}

writeStream = null;

return Result.Ok();
```

I know I shouldn;t have to close/dispose and nullify the stream, but this was just a wild guess (and makes no difference).

When i use dotTrace, or the analysiers from Visual studio, I still see that my memorystream is big (with every upload, it grows).

I have run out of ideas what it could be, do you have a suggestion?

Nevertheless; I will run into problems with this memorystream, is it possible to use something like, upload a few bytes, and upload(append it) to the ftp-upload?
We will be processing 4K-video content, witch could be very very big (bigger then the RAM that we have in place :) )
pls don't say filestreams ;)

Comment: That's normal in .NET. Disposing, closing, nullifying `MemoryStream` will not reclaim its memory. Memory is reclaimed by garbage collector at indeterminate time. Do you have actual problem (like OutOfMemoryException) or only a potential one? Also, why not just `blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(writeStream)` without proxifying data through that memory stream?

Comment: @Evk i thoguht so, i was hoping I could speed things up ;) It is a potential one, our infra-team was tapping on my fingers, that our docker platform was  sqeeking ;) the not-proxifyng option sounds good, but with the interfaces that i have, I cannot find a way.. Am i missing something?

Comment: By itself memory growth is kind of "ok" in .NET applications. If your server has plenty of memory, and that memory is not used by applications - there is not much harm for garbage collector to wait and not reclaim any memory (to not interrupt current application activities). Then at some future point it will reclaim it eventually (unless you have a memory leak which is not the case here). Still in your case it seems possible to stream right from azure blob directly to file (opened by `client.OpenFileWriteStreamAsync`) and if that's indeed possible - better avoid intermediate memory stream.

Comment: worked like a charm! Needed to change some interfaces, i was afraid that it was a azure interface :) thnx!